# Continue to for-loop items again

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have code like that:

```
for(i=0; i<15; i++) {listitems[i].style.width=100px;}
```

for looping items. But my item count (for example, 10) is less than the number i (15) in for loop. I want to it continue to loop items again after i=10, like this:

```
i=11 ==> listitems[1]...;
i=12 ==> listitems[2]...;
```

... etc. while it is not `i=15`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not just loop while `i < 10` or `i < listitems.length`?

Comment: yes I know, but I have a little bit different code structure. I have color items in array and their count is 10, but I want to use them in 15 div elements.

Comment: Then post *that* example.  It makes much more sense than assigning the same width to an element multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of your precise goal but you seem to want this :

```
for(i=0; i<15; i++) { listitems[i%listitems.length].style.width=100px;}
```

The loop will iterate over

```
listitems[0]
listitems[1]
...
listitems[9]
listitems[0]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of your `for loop` add a **condition** :

```
for(i=0; i<15; i++) {
    var index = i <= (listitems.length -1) ? i : (i - listitems.length);

    listitems[index].style.width=100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(i=0,j=0; i<15; i++) 
   {
      listitems[j].style.width=100px;
      j++;

       if(i==10)
       {
            j=1;
       }

      }
```